# Sql, Create a foreign key to table with a primary key composed of multiple columns

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have the following table:

```
CREATE TABLE Appartment
(
    SizeSquareMeter INT,
    Type VARCHAR(30) NOT NULL,
    StreetName VARCHAR(30) NOT NULL,
    Number INT NOT NULL,
    Door INT  NOT NULL,

    CONSTRAINT App_Address PRIMARY KEY(StreetName, Number, Door)
)
```

And I need to create the following table as well

```
CREATE TABLE Resident
(
    RID INT PRIMARY KEY NOT NULL,
    FirstName VARCHAR(30) NOT NULL,
    LastName VARCHAR(30) NOT NULL,
    BirthDate DATE NOT NULL,
    StreetName VARCHAR(30) NOT NULL,
    Number INT NOT NULL,
    Door INT NOT NULL,

    CONSTRAINT Resident_Address 
        FOREIGN KEY (StreetName, Number, Door) REFERENCES Appartment(StreetName, Number, Door)
)
```

Now the above works but it duplicates the address and I don't want that, is there a way I can create a foreign key from `Resident` to `Appartment` **without duplicating the address and without creating a new PRIMARY KEY for** `Appartment`?

**Note:** whether it's important or not it basically should be valid Microsoft DDL.

Comment: No, you **cannot** - since your PK in `Appartment` is made up of these three columns, any table referencing **must also** have those three columns to make the FK connection. The only way would be to use a **surrogate** primary key (an artificial, new e.g. `AppartmentId`) to avoid this

Comment: @HimanshuAhuja I assume it can, basically I need to keep a unique combination of these 3 fields but if I add a different int field as a primary key, will the unique constraint hold with different primary keys having the same address fields?

Comment: Assumption is wrong it wouldnt hold if additional fields are added with the composite unique key as it would result into redundancy somewhere around result is normalisation or seperate id which is either unique or primary key itself Unique constraint though will make sure that your foreign key doesnt get redundant data in it but adding other columns to it which are not primary key will still result in redundancy

Comment: In actual for composite if you could make Primary key as Unique(All Fields) in one table Foriegn Key referencing (All fields ) to that table then only it ll be acheived else not.

Comment: @HimanshuAhuja I'm not fully understanding, could you write this option as an answer?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A foreign key reference can be to any unique key(s) in the table.  So you can do:

```
CREATE TABLE Appartment (
    AppartmentId int identity unique not null,
    SizeSquareMeter INT,
    Type VARCHAR(30) NOT NULL,
    StreetName VARCHAR(30) NOT NULL,
    Number INT NOT NULL,
    Door INT  NOT NULL,

    CONSTRAINT App_Address PRIMARY KEY(StreetName, Number, Door)
);

CREATE TABLE Resident (
    RID INT PRIMARY KEY NOT NULL,
    FirstName VARCHAR(30) NOT NULL,
    LastName VARCHAR(30) NOT NULL,
    BirthDate DATE NOT NULL,
    AppartmentId int not null,

    CONSTRAINT Resident_Address 
        FOREIGN KEY (AppartmentId) REFERENCES Appartment(AppartmentId)
);
```

That said, I strongly think you should change the data structure so the primary key for the apartment table is an `identity` column.

Comment: Thank you, I know I should change it, I'll see what I can do about that.

Answer (score 1):

You can use only specific Id to do the foreign key. It is breaking the normalization rule(when you using same detail in both tables). Basicly you can create a UniqueId on the Appartment table. Remove StreetName, Number and Door from the Resident table which is already registered in Appartment table. Add AppartmentId to the Resident with the foreign key. Here is the updated create sample :

```
CREATE TABLE Appartment(
    ApartmentId INT NOT NULL ,
    SizeSquareMeter int,
    Type varchar(30) NOT NULL,
    StreetName varchar(30) NOT NULL,
    Number int NOT NULL,
    Door int NOT NULL,
    CONSTRAINT PK_Appartment PRIMARY KEY(ApartmentId)
)


CREATE TABLE Resident(
    RID int PRIMARY KEY NOT NULL,
    AppartmentId INT NOT NULL,
    FirstName varchar(30) NOT NULL,
    LastName varchar(30) NOT NULL,
    BirthDate Date NOT NULL,
    CONSTRAINT FK_Resident_Address FOREIGN KEY (AppartmentId) REFERENCES Appartment
)
```

Comment: I already thought of this solution, that is why my question states `without creating a new PRIMARY KEY for Appartment`, it's just that according to my specification that I cannot change the combination of 3 of the address fields compose the primary key, do you know a way around without manipulating `Appartment`?